# lxc - should zfs-backed container have their rootfs unmounted after being stopped?

Tags: zfs, lxc

I'm using lxc and zfs on Ubuntu 16.04.

When I stop a container, the zfs /lxc/containername/rootfs volume is left mounted.

Should stopping a container unmount its storage?

Do mounted zfs filesystems consume memory?  i.e. do I need to unmount it?